# JsonCpp - when having a json::Value object, how can i know it's key name?

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

Let suppose I have this Json file:

```
[
    {
        "id": 0
    }
]
```

using jsoncpp, i can have a `Json::Value` object by doing this:

```
Json::Value node = root[0u]["id"];
```

OK, somewhere else in the code, I'm getting that `node` object, and I want to get some info out of it. I can get its value, like this:

```
int node_value = node.asInt();
```

But how can I get its NAME? (i.e the "id"). It should be something like:

```
string node_name  = node.Name(); //or maybe:
string node_name2 = node.Key();
```

but I can't find anything similar. Help? How can I get a node's name?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use Json::Value::getMemberNames() to iterate through the names.

```
Json::Value value;
for (auto const& id : value.getMemberNames()) {
    std::cout << id << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: But this means I have to get to the parent of the Value object I have (Which is another unanswered question of mine). IS there a way to get to a Value object's parent?

Comment: There is no way to get the parent of a Value as far as I know; why do you need it? What is your use case?

Comment: I've been asked to write a wrapper to the jsoncpp library, with a way to traverse the tree of the json. I assumed jsoncpp already took care of that and I just have to find out how.

Answer (score 1):

You need an up-pointer? It's not a bad idea, but adding a field for the up-pointer would break binary-compatibility ([which is very important](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/releases/tag/0.8.0)). So yes, you need to wrap it.

Currently, a sub-value is just a `Value`, like any other.